# how to fetch 3 months data excluding data of weekends of every month

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
Select temp, DATE_FORMAT(temp,'%b-%d') from test
where temp between
    concat(year(now()),'-',month(now()) -3,'-', DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%d'))
        and
    (curdate());
```

I'm using this query to fetch data for 3 months including 7 days a week but i'm not getting results as expected, how can i get data for 5 days a week by this query and ignoring weekend data from database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`DAYOFWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function, which returns values ranging from `1` (for Sunday) to `7` (for Saturday):

```
SELECT temp, DATE_FORMAT(temp,'%b-%d') FROM test
WHERE
    DAYOFWEEK(temp) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
        AND
    temp BETWEEN
        CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(NOW())-3,'-',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d'))
            AND
        (CURDATE());
```

Do note however that your conditions for selecting data for the last 3 months look a little suspicious. Probably simpler doing something like:

```
SELECT temp, DATE_FORMAT(temp,'%b-%d') FROM test
WHERE
    DAYOFWEEK(temp) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
        AND
    temp >= NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
```